# WiX properties RefProjectOutputGroups RefTargetDir

Tags: wix, msbuild-projectreference

When referencing projects within WiX projects (*.wixproj) I often saw the code snippet

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Foo.Bar\Foo.Bar.csproj">
    <Name>Foo.Bar</Name>
    <Project>{0bd367ce-5072-4161-8447-ff4deed97bd4}</Project>
    <Private>True</Private>
    <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
    <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
    <RefTargetDir>INSTALLLOCATION</RefTargetDir>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Can anyone explain to me what the properties `DoNotHarvest`, `RefProjectOutputGroups`, and `RefTargetDir` mean? Or point to some documentation? I couldn't find anything explaining the meaning of these properties (including the WiX documentation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are disabled features for automatic reference project harvesting. The feature is disabled because it was found to have many bugs.

- When you change `DoNotHarvest` to `false` (double negatives are fun) the feature will sort of turn back on (but other things will be broken).
- `RefProjectOutputGroups` lists the project outputs from the referenced project to include in a generated `ComponentGroup`.
- `RefTargetDir` specifies the `Directory` that is used for all the generated `Components`.

As noted above, it's not documented because the feature does not currently work.

Comment: Does this mean that it's actually enough to include a `DoNotHarvest` set to `false` and don't mention the other two properties at all? Or does/can this break anything now/in the future?

Comment: The feature is disabled and if/when it comes back it'll be built to handle all the cases of the data missing/etc. So, for now I'd say you can ignore it all.

Comment: Is it still broken?